# With Vue3 defineComponent method can not access data property, data = undefined

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I want to flip an overlay component on or off, using a method `toggleOverlay()` that changes a boolean `showOverlay`. But I'm getting confused, many examples on the web look the same and work. But my version doesn't. In this method, I can not access the **data** because `this` is *undefined*.

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import TrendingTVShow from '@/components/TrendingTVShow.vue';
  import TVShowOverlay from '@/components/TVShowOverlay.vue';
  import type { Show } from "@/tvAppTypes";

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      TrendingTVShow, TVShowOverlay,
    },
    methods: {
      toggleOverlay: (): void => {
        console.log(this); // = undefined ???

        this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay; // Flip the BOOLEAN, show or hide <TVShowOverlay>

        console.log(showOverlay); // Unhandled error during execution of native event handler at <TrendingTVShow onClick=fn<bound toggleOverlay> tvShow= 
      },
    },
    props: {
      tvShows: {
        type: Array<Show>,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showOverlay: false,
      };
    },
  });
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <TrendingTVShow @click="toggleOverlay" :tvShow="tvShow[0]"></TrendingTVShow>
    <TVShowOverlay v-if="showOverlay" :tvShow="tvShow[0]" :toggle="toggleOverlay"></TVShowOverlay>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: What if you didn't use an arrow function?

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't have bindings to `this` and should not be used as methods - MDN

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by al the examples, based on Vue without Typescript. But I finally see my mistakes. Completely overlooked the `setup()` method of the `defineComponent()` function.
It is also more simpler.

```js
  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      TrendingTVShow, TVShowOverlay,
    },
    props: {
      tvShows: {
        type: Array<Show>, // Object as PropType<Show>,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    setup( props ): any {
      const randomShow = props.tvShows[Math.floor(Math.random() * props.tvShows.length)];
      const showOverlay = ref<boolean>();
      const toggleOverlay = () => {
        showOverlay.value = !showOverlay.value;
      }
      showOverlay.value = false;
      return { randomShow, toggleOverlay, showOverlay }
    }
  });
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <h1>On air now</h1>
    <TrendingTVShow @click="toggleOverlay" :tvShow="randomShow"></TrendingTVShow>
    <TVShowOverlay v-if="showOverlay" :tvShow="randomShow" :toggle="toggleOverlay"></TVShowOverlay>
  </main>
</template>
```